# How to delegate a call to a method in json_serialization?

Tags: flutter, dart, json-serialization, json-annotation

I've two classes `Foo` and `Bar`:

```dart
@JsonSerializable()
class Foo {
  final Bar bar;
  Foo(this.bar);

  factory Foo.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$FooFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$FooToJson(this);
}

@JsonSerializable()
class Bar {
  final String s;
  Bar(this.s);

  factory Bar.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$BarFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$BarToJson(this);
}
```

Once the code is generated, I use:

```dart
final bar = Bar('hi');
final foo = Foo(bar);
print(foo.toJson());
```

The above line prints

```
{bar: Instance of 'Bar'}
```

but I want it to print

```
{bar: "hi"}
```

The one way is to override `toString` method in the `Bar` class but I don't think it's a good way when using `json_serializable` for code generation. I think there's trivial property I am missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For having custom class inside another class you need to use `explicitToJson: true` in your target class.

```
@JsonSerializable(explicitToJson: true)
class Foo {
  final Bar bar;
  Foo(this.bar);

  factory Foo.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$FooFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$FooToJson(this);
}
```